# How to use trigger in sql to create a certain attribute

Tags: mysql, sql, database, attributes, constants

I have a question here. If a car that is under service is not available to be rented out. Then how do I create an attribute titled 'availability' that determines whether a car is available to be rented out? By using the trigger effect/or any other conventional method, how can I create an availability attribute that determines whether the car can be rented out based on the service period in this table.

```
CREATE TABLE VehicleService (
vehicleServiceID    int (16) AUTO_INCREMENT,
vehiclePlateNumber  varchar (8),
serviceStartDate    datetime,
serviceEndDate      datetime,
servicePeriod   int(4)  AS (TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, serviceStartDate, serviceEndDate))
location     varchar(255)
CONSTRAINT pkvehicleServiceID PRIMARY KEY (vehicleServiceID),
CONSTRAINT fkvehiclePlateNumber FOREIGN KEY (vehiclePlateNumber) REFERENCES Vehicle 
(vehiclePlateNumber));
```

Comment: Checking availability of a car implies you have a specific day in mind. Which day does the client want to rent the car? Always today?

Comment: The client can pick a specific date to rent the car and return the car. The number of days rent are whole numbers  only (INT). Basically, we are letting the client know whether the car is available or not before they could rent it. The way it works is they want to rent a car and while they search for it, they can check to see if the vehicle is   available or not.

Answer (score 0):

If the client can pick any arbitrary date they want to check for availability, then the attribute you want would have a different value for each client, depending on the date they want to check. Therefore you can't persist the availability as an attribute. You can only calculate it per query.

```
SELECT ? BETWEEN serviceStartDate AND serviceEndDate AS is_available
WHERE vehicleServiceId = ?
```

The first `?` would be the date the client is interested in checking.

---

Re your comment:

Okay, let's do an example.

| vehicleServiceId | serviceStartDate | serviceEndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2022-02-18 | 2022-02-22 |

Suppose I search for availability for date 2022-02-20. The car is in service, so it is not available.

Concurrently, you search for availability for date 2022-02-24. The service should be done, so it is available.

Regardless of how we implement it, what value do you think should be stored in the hypothetical availability attribute that you want in the table? True or false?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion but I don't really want it to be a query.I want to have it in the table. Let's say the car by default is available. If by any chance a customer happens to rent the car to be used between the service period, it will be indicated unavailable and the database rejects the rental entry. Is there a way to code this as a trigger event maybe or any other method?

Comment: Yes something like ENUM( 'Y', 'N') should be the data type for the availability attribute.

Comment: Fine, it can be 'Y' or 'N' instead of true or false. But you can only store one value at a time on a given row. Which one of these two values should be stored for the example row I show above?

Comment: Yikes, now that I think about it, you are right. There isn't a way to automatically update the availability of rental of that chosen vehicle. But answering your question, I suppose it should be N ( for No ) since the rental takes place between the service period.

Comment: So in the example I show above, if the value stored on the row is 'N', then both my search and your search get a result of 'N'. This is correct for my search, but not correct for your search, because you want the rental on a date after the service dates.

Comment: How the update is implemented is actually not the problem. The problem is that the row can store only one value at a time. You need the result to be relative to the specific date the client is searching for.

Comment: Actually hold on, if it can be updated then I guess its okay. Ï was thinking of like once the service period is over, it should be dropped via DELETE CASCADE and then the value of availability should change from N to Y automatically based on current date. 
 Hence if service were to take place in the future, then its still available based on current date or if it had already happened then use UPDATE/DELETE CASCADE to get rid of its service ID so it reverts back to being available. I apologize for my long paragraphs. Perhaps I could chat up with you about this issue if you are okay with it ?

Comment: No, you are still not getting it. Clients can query concurrently, but they each query for availability **on different dates**.

Comment: Ah okay I understand.  I will need some time to digest this and perhaps discuss this with my groupmates. Much appreciated and cheers